# How to pass a parameter to an action in a form on struts 2?

Tags: forms, jsp, struts2

I have a jsp page to show the details of one product and I have a form to add comments to this one.

The form is:

```
<s:form action="AddComment>
    <s:textarea key="commentDetails" rows="5" cols="50" />
    <s:submit key="details.submit" />
</s:form>
```

I need to pass to the `AddComment` action, the id of the product which is in `request.prodAprob.id`.

Comment: And the problem is? You must have a corresponding Struts action defined.

Comment: I don't know how to pass the value of request.prodAprob.id to the action AddComment. I have already defined the action in struts.xml.

Comment: What is `request.prodAprob.id`, a servlet request attribute? In general you need the parameter in the form as well.

Comment: But my question is how I do it. For example, I proved with the tag `<param>` with `<s:param name="product"><s:property value="%{#request.prodAprob.id}/></s:param>` but it doesn't work.

Comment: And yes, it is a servlet request attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
<s:form action="AddComment>
    <s:hidden name="product" value="%{#request.prodAprob.id}"/>
    <s:textarea key="commentDetails" rows="5" cols="50" />
    <s:submit key="details.submit" />
</s:form>
```

Comment: Or just `value="${prodAprob.id}"` assuming JSP EL is enabled.